# Missing "missing Produce outputs on build" option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I created brand new .NET core class library project in visual studio 2015.
The generated class has comment:

```
// This project can output the Class library as a NuGet Package.
// To enable this option, right-click on the project and select the Properties menu item. In the Build tab select "Produce outputs on build".
```

I have Visual studio Enterprise 2015, Update 2

But the problem is I don't see this option in project settings:
[image]

[image]

Where do I get this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even i am facing similar problem in VS2015 update 2.
After building the project, i used to get nuget package as output, but now in the build menu, we do not see the option 'produce output on build".

I was able to get the nuget package using the below steps:

1. Open VS2015 developer command prompt
2. change directory to your project's project.json location
3. run " dotnet pack" and it creates a nuget package of your project in 
   project_folder/bin/debug

Answer (score 3):

Pre-.NET Core RC2, your code was magically compiled into memory. This sometimes caused issues so you were given the option to produce physical output.

I don't have any proof to link you to right now, but I know it was said that this caused more problems than it was worth and RC2 only compiles to disk; therefore the option is no longer available.

The test you see might be left over from the project templates, or a project that was started in RC1 that is now upgraded to RC2.